# Unity random object generation always returning same object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the vertical game, I am creating random blocks spawn within a 100f. I am randomly creating 3 different types of objects which are 'platforms' 'boostplatforms' and 'breakableplatforms'. My code for generating all of these give no errors and when I run the game the blocks generated when I check the activity however visually only the objects named 'platform' appear.

The coding I used for this was:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject platformPrefab;
    public GameObject platformPrefab2;
    public GameObject platformPrefab3;

    public int numberOfPlatforms = 999;
    public int numberOfBoostPlatforms = 999;
    public int numberOfBreakablePlatforms = 999;
    public float levelWidth = 100f;
    public float minY = 55f;
    public float maxY = 120f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Vector3 startPosition = new Vector3 ();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlatforms; i++) 
        {
            startPosition.y += Random.Range (minY, maxY);
            startPosition.x = Random.Range (-levelWidth, levelWidth);
            Instantiate (platformPrefab, startPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBoostPlatforms; i++) 
        {
            startPosition.y += Random.Range (minY, maxY);
            startPosition.x = Random.Range (-levelWidth, levelWidth);
            Instantiate (platformPrefab2, startPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBreakablePlatforms; i++) 
        {
            startPosition.y += Random.Range (minY, maxY);
            startPosition.x = Random.Range (-levelWidth, levelWidth);
            Instantiate (platformPrefab3, startPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: If all the blocks generated properly, they must be in the hierarchy view of unity. Can you see them there? If yes, are they in a realistic location?

Comment: Did you assign the prefabs correctly in the inspector?

Comment: Despite the specific issue, are you generating almost 3000 objects in a scene? It seems like a sort of stress test, for the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I would recommend the following:

1. Verify that your prefab variables are set to the correct prefabs.
2. Notice that each platform's Y position is cumulative. Verify that the boost and break platforms aren't simply spawning after all of the standard platforms (which they will be based on your code).
3. Switch to object pooling. You are spawning 3,000 objects in a single frame even though the majority won't even be visible. The idea would be to spawn a small pool, 10 of each let's say, and when a new platform is needed (coming into view) you recycle one of the existing objects that is no longer visible or needed. [Unity's Object Pooling tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling)